# exit ios application in air

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, soft-keyboard

I am unable to find a way out to exit/close a flex application developed in air 3.2 for ios

Also i am unable to raise softkeyoard using requestSoftKeyboard() method as its not there for ios , so is there an alternative way to handle this?

I have tried these using latest air 3.2 version available.
It seems its not easy to develop things in flex for ios as many features are not available.

Can anyone please tell me how to do manage these two things?

Looking forward to it.

Comment: It is not possible to close an iOS app programmatically. As I remember this is a licensing issue. Only closing by using the "Home" button is allowed.  Regarding soft keyboard maybe this can help http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Raising_the_soft_keyboard_programmatically-19215.html

Comment: Thanks but in the link provided for softkeyboard , says its not for iOS and only android.

Comment: iOS has no such thing as a softKeyboard.  All keyboards come from the system.

Comment: i guess the keyboard that pops up when we need to enter text , is called softKeyboard. And we all know its there in ipad/iphone. But how to initiate it programically is a problem